# Switched to postgres user after PostgreSQL install, can't switch back to normal user

Tags: apt, permissions, password, users, postgresql

I installed PostgreSQL using this guide:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-18-04

It says that the install command created a Linux user `postgres` automatically.
So I used

```
sudo -i -u postgres
```

to switch to `postgres` user
It went well and I could then use

```
psql
```

command to be able to use SQL queries.

Now I want to go back to my normal user, but I can't.

I tried

```
sudo -i -u username
```

but it asks for `postgres` password. I have no idea what it is since I didn't set it. I simply used

```
sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

command to install PostgreSQL and it created the `postgres` user and set its password for me.

Why does it ask for `postgres` password and not for `username` password? How can I switch back to my normal user?

Comment: Use the command `exit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Use the command exit (two times) worked for me to get back to normal user. See following